# polymer-ide could not trigger snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, polymer

I have installed polymer-ide ext on vscode.
I couldn't find a way to access snippets.
For example how to triger/insert 'PolymerElement' kind of creation snip on an empty file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`polymer-ide` does not provide code snippets but rather provides only the following [features](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=polymer.polymer-ide):

- typeahead completions for imported elements, with documentation
- typeahead completions for element attributes, with documentation
- inline errors (squiggle underlines)
- jump to definition support for custom elements and attributes

Instead, you might be interested in [Polymer Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chimon2000.polymer-snippets) or [Polymer 2 Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=justinribeiro.Polymer2Snippets). For the Polymer Snippets, you could use the `pe` snippet in an empty `*.html` file to create a new Polymer element (by typing `pe` and then <kbd>TAB</kbd>). And for Polymer 2 Snippets, you could use `p-webcomponent` for a Polymer-2 equivalent.